# How to configure multiple options within a loop?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I'm using .Net 5 and have multiple configuration sections. Currently I register all of them like so

```
services
    .Configure<MyClass1>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MyClass1"))
    .Configure<MyClass2>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MyClass2"))
    .Configure<MyClass3>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MyClass3"));
```

Is there a way to configure them within a loop? I tried to create a class holding the configuration model type and the section and loop through a collection of it

```
foreach (var configurationSection in configurationSections)
{
    var configurationSection = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(configurationSection.Section);
    services.Configure<typeof(configurationSection.Type)>(configurationSection);
}
```

but obviously it's not possible to pass in the model type as a generic parameter.

Do I have to use the long way or are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done by reflection.
It's totally possible to call generic methods.

```csharp
MethodInfo method = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions).GetMethod("Configure", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (var configurationSection in configurationSections)
{
    var configurationSection = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(configurationSection.Section);
    //Construct and call generic method:
    var configureMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(configurationSection.Type);
    configureMethod?.Invoke(null, new object[]{services, configurationSection});
}
```

UPD: As mentioned by @Llama Configure is an extension method, so we need to get it instead.